# Web service in C# date format issues

Tags: c#, web-services

In client side i'm getting wrong date format eg("/Date(1373950800000)/")
I need to change standard date format

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
JSONString = js.Serialize(objUserDetReturn);
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDetails>(JSONString);
return result;
```

Comment: myDate = new Date(1000*myObj.date_created); try this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format a Microsoft JSON date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/format-a-microsoft-json-date)

Comment: @Saravanan thanks for ur reply. I need to change in server side ,.because everytime i dont want to change in client side . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the result in `JS` using something like

```
var result = jsonResponse; //your json result
var date = new Date(parseInt(result.Date.substr(6)));
```

Comment: Good one , this is working in client side. but i need to change in server side ..